# Hacer un login auth con Django

Tags: django, login, sesiones, auth

estoy aprendiendo a programar y tengo una duda, tengo un proyecto donde no he creado ningun modelo en las aplicaciones de Django ya que estoy tomando directamente los datos desde una base de datos MySql que ya estaba hecha, haciendo consultas,pero me gustaria hacer un login, estoy intentando el metodo por default de django pero no me funciona, me gustaria saber que me recomiendan hacer, les dejo mi

view

```
def webLogin(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']

    user = auth.authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        redirect('login')

return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
```

parte del template

```
 <form action="{% url 'login' %}"method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group">
             <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">
          </div> <!-- form-group// -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
          </div> <!-- form-group// -->
```

la url

```
 path('login/', views.webLogin, name="login"),
```

Muchisimas gracias de antemano

Comment: Creo que esto tiene mucho que ver con [tu pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/528557/como-manejar-una-base-de-datos-existente-en-django). Aquí yo lo que haría es intentar consumir la base de datos que te gusta de otra manera. Con Django utiliza su ORM para al menos el sistema de autenticación. 
Si no vas a usar nada del ORM de Django, quizás no tenga sentido hacer tu proyecto en Django.

Comment: y no hay forma de hacer un modelo solo trayendo los datos desde la base de datos? ejemplo `class Accounts(models.Models):
    name = "SELECT name FROM accounts"` o algo similar?, para poder seguir trayendo los decoradores como Accounts.objects.get()

Answer (score 0):

Listo, todo lo que hice fue seguir este articulo
https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/django-1-0/capitulo-16/integracion-con-una-base-de-datos-existente

y me paso todas las tablas desde la base de datos MySQL hacia el archivo models.py, ya tengo todos los modelos copiados desde mysql solo con 1 linea de codigo $ py manage.py inspectdb > accounts/models.py

Comment: Genial! Entendí mal tu cuestión, pensaba que no querías usar el ORM de Django para tu base de datos existente.

Comment: si, es que no sabia que podria extraer la base de datos para usar el ORM, ya que la base de datos que tengo existente es bastante amplia y no queria copias las tablas 1 por 1, pero el comando inspectdb me sirvio perfectamente